# Code Error - Java Savings Account

Tags: java

There is an output mess-up, which converts all of my balances to 0.000000

Here is my code:

```
package savingsaccountclass;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SavingsAccountClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double annualInterestRate;
        double savingsBalance;
        double[] postInterestBalance = new double[100];
        int counter = 0;

        Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the current annual interest rate");
        annualInterestRate = entry.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the current balance.");
        savingsBalance = entry.nextDouble();

        while (counter < 12)
        {
            postInterestBalance[counter] = calculateMonthlyInterest(savingsBalance, annualInterestRate);
            System.out.printf("After Month %d. %f\n", counter + 1, postInterestBalance[counter]);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public static double calculateMonthlyInterest(double balance, double interest)
    {
        double[] array = new double[100];
        int c = 0;
        double done = (balance * (interest/12));
        while (c < 12)
        {
            array[c] = (((c + 1) * done) + balance);
            c++;
        }
        return array[c];
    }
}
```

And here is my output:

```
run:
Enter the current annual interest rate
1
Enter the current balance.
100
After Month 1. 0.000000
After Month 2. 0.000000
After Month 3. 0.000000
After Month 4. 0.000000
After Month 5. 0.000000
After Month 6. 0.000000
After Month 7. 0.000000
After Month 8. 0.000000
After Month 9. 0.000000
After Month 10. 0.000000
After Month 11. 0.000000
After Month 12. 0.000000
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

If someone could let me know why everything is converted into 0, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks :)

Comment: But when it adds balance it would still be above 0, right?

Comment: @RomainHippeau No, interest is a `double`.

Comment: And I tried setting Interest to 100, it still didn't work.

Comment: If it were me I'd just assume my wife spent it all.............

Comment: In your last step you increment c and return the wrong index

Answer (score 3):

You are filling out the first `12` balances in the array, but you are returning `array[12]`, which was never assigned, so it's `0`.

Return `array[c - 1]` to return the last filled in element of the array.

Additionally, your interest rate of `1` is being interpreted as 100%, in that 100/12, or 8 1/3 % is being added each month.  Divide the interest rate by `100` to convert from percentage to the decimal needed.

Also, you aren't calculating compound interest currently.  You are currenlty calculating the interest currently for each "month" on the initial balance `100`.  Instead, you'll need to calculate the monthly interest based on the previous month's balance, not the initial balance, using `array[c - 1]` to access the previous month's balance.

Comment: Thanks! I made c = 0 just before the last return statement, and now it's only returning that first month. How can I make it so that it returns the 1st month, then 2nd, then 3rd...etc?

Thanks for all your help though, I really appreciate it!